# Need to rewrite URL contain # tag in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, single-page-application, redirect

I need to rewrite URL in .htaccess? Here below is a description of my problem.

URL: www.example.com/about.php#vision

Needs to be rewritten as: www.example.com/vison.html

I tried this as mentioned in below, but it does not work

```
RewriteRule ^vison.html$ about.php#vision [L]
RewriteRule ^our-vision.html(.*)$ about.php$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is not a query string. This is a client side stuff. This will not work. You can only rewrite query-strings or other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: it is not at all possible using .htaccess!

A longer answer:

The part after the `#` character is not sent from the browser to the web server, as it is only used client-side.

That type of "rewriting" must take place using client-side JavaScript.

The [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event might be a starting-point for you:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
    window.location.href = "/" + hash + ".html";
});
```

You should also look up SPAs *(single page applications)*. There are lots of frameworks that will help you build solutions like these. Also, there are much more modern techniques that don't rely on hashes, like the [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) event and the mechanisms surrounding it.

A couple of frameworks that could help you get started:

- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)
- [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/)

**Update**

When looking at your current **.htaccess** setup, it looks as if you want to do the reverse of what your question text implies - when someone requests the `vison.html`, you want to redirect them to `about.php#vision` - and **not the other way around**.

If that is true, then yes, you can do it using .htaccess by adding the `R` flag *(REDIRECT)* and also the `NE` flag *(NO ESCAPE)* to prevent the `#` character from being encoded:

```
RewriteRule ^vison.html$ about.php#vision [NE,R,L]
```